# Are there any standards for HTTP over Port 8080?

Tags: http, tcp, http-headers, port

I have been using port 80 over TCP to reduce my search to HTTP headers in pcaps I have obtained for various analyses, including analysis of malicious HTTP headers/payloads.

I am thinking about using port 8080 for header information as well. Can I ignore port 8080? If not, does it follow common HTTP standards over port 80, or can it be used for anything?

Answer (score 0):

There is no restriction on the port you can use. While 80 is reserved for HTTP you often see HTTP (proxy) traffic on 8080, 3128 (default port of squid proxy), 8888 and 8000. And of course it can be more ports. So it depends on the kind of analysis you do if you include everything which looks like HTTP independent from the port or if you just consider common ports.